# Error when using Elasticsearch client's scan() API

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following Python code to query my ES cluster (v8.8.0).

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

for i in range(0, 100):
    s = Search(using=es, index=index_name) \
          .filter('range', **{'@timestamp': {'gte': start_datetime, 'lt': end_datetime, 'format': 
    'strict_date_optional_time_nanos'}})

    if s.count() > 0:
       results = s.scan()
       for result in results:
           result_json = result.to_dict()
           res1, res2 = process_result(result_json)
```

The number of documents returned in each `scan` is between 1-2M, with each document about 500-800 bytes.

During one of the queries, I got an error on ES:

> circuit_breaking_exception: [parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [32283148058/30gb], which is larger than the limit of [31621696716/29.4gb], real usage: [32283146480/30gb], new bytes reserved: [1578/1.5kb]...

I've ran the loop a couple of times (different post-processing of the results) prior to getting the error, and had no problem. The size of the data mentioned in the error (32GB) is also much larger than the size of the results from a single call of `scan`.

Someone else advised that it could be because the cache was not cleared, so ES eventually ran out of memory after so many calls. Although it seems like `scan` by default has `clear_scroll=True`, based on its [doc](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/helpers.html#scan).

Is there something I can specify in my query so as to avoid this issue? For example, should I set `scroll` or `request_timeout` to make sure the cache is cleared after each call to `scan`, maybe with an addition of `sleep` to make sure the timeout is met?

Also, if `clear_scroll=True` by default, then I would not need to explicitly clear the scroll_id, is that correct?

Comment: Can you check amount of available memory on elasticsearch while you are seeing this error message? Also try running it with size parameter set to something small like 10, and increase it to see how that works.